# Create a "watch" for new list item

Tags: workflow, alert, list-item

Hello I am wondering if it is possible to use alerts or workflows to help me with the following problem.

Background: At my company, our suppliers upload documentation to our SharePoint site as a new workflow, which is then reviewed and approved by any one of many reviewers. Sometimes however, the supplier has not uploaded any data yet, which puts our work on hold.  We will notify the supplier, who (should) then create the workflow as they normally would.  The problem is that we don't get any notification when that new workflow is created, so that particular item will sit on our desk, and we have to check daily to see if the data has been uploaded.

What I want to know is if it's possible to somehow create an alert, just for me, that a specific item has been created. I know I can be alerted when any new items are created, but I just want to know if/when, for instance, a new item called "PO1234567890" has been created.  Even better if I can do this in a workflow, because there are a couple more steps I would like to do.

Another solution I've considered is having the reviewer create the empty workflow and then have the supplier add to it, but I don't think that is feasible.

*Edit* SharePoint 2010

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you know the item name(s) you are looking for you can put them in a new list, e.g. Missing File List.  Then you can create a workflow on the Supplier List that looks to see if the new item (e.g. PO1234567890) added to the Supplier List matches an item in the Missing File List, if it does send a notification.  You could also extend the Missing File List to include who should be notified by the workflow.